# Are correlation functions $\langle \phi(x_{1}) \cdots\phi(x_{n}) \rangle $ invariant under cyclic permutations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions

If I have a correlation function $$\langle \phi(x_{1}) \phi(x_{2}) \cdots \phi(x_{n-1}) \phi(x_{n})\rangle ,$$ can I cycle through the fields?

I'm not sure I'm using the correct terminology. But for example, is it true that $$\langle \phi(x_{1})\phi(x_{2})\phi(x_{3})\rangle = \langle\phi(x_{2})\phi(x_{3})\phi(x_{1})\rangle = \langle \phi(x_{3})\phi(x_{1})\phi(x_{2})\rangle ~?$$

I think this is not true... but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: What do you mean by a correlation function? if it involves the time-ordered mean value of the fields, so their order is not important because a time order would affect them and so they are equal.

Comment: What is $\cdot$? Moyal star?

Comment: A precise definition of what you're thinking of as a correlation function would be useful. For example, the fields could be time ordered, or they could be radially ordered, rendering their order not important. However, if they happen to be Grassman objects, every time you commute the fields your expression would gain an extra minus sign. Hope this is useful.

Comment: What you are looking for is 'cyclic permutations.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the action $S$ of the quantum field theory. In general, correlation functions are clearly not invariant under cyclic permutations. Simply take fermion fields $\psi(x_1),\psi(x_2)$, these fields are Grassmannian numbers (i.e. mathematical objects with $ab = - ba$ for any Grassmann numbers $a,b$). The propagator $<\psi(x_1),\psi(x_2)> \mapsto <\psi(x_2),\psi(x_1)> = - <\psi(x_1),\psi(x_2)>$ is clearly not invariant under cyclic permutations.